# Cheap alternative to cutting boards

Tags: hand-tools

I need a cutting board for my leather project. The ones you can buy at the hobby store are ridiculously expensive the bigger board is the more insane goes the price. I dont believe the material of which these boards are made contributes to their prices so much (it is comparable to sheet steel, come on). So I think there must be a cheaper alternative to those cutting boards. If there is one, what is it?

Comment: a piece of wood?

Answer (score 4):

Cutting boards serve two purposes: to keep you from cutting into your bench top, and to keep from dulling your cutting tools. The second reason is the kicker!  You could use a sheet of metal, but your blades would need constant resharpening.

All that being said, I would go to your local Walmart, Target, Fred Meyer, etc and buy a cheap cutting board made for kitchen use.  They work well, and are way less expensive than the ones you'll find at Tandy Leather...

Answer (score 3):

In my leather working days (forty years ago) the board of choice for cutting and stamping leather was tempered hardboard. You can find a 2 ft by 4 ft piece for under $10 in a big box store.

Answer (score 2):

Some scrap cedar (2x10) from big box stores.